# Отправка почты на Go

Tags: сервер, golang, smtp, email

Как должна работать почта? Точнее, мне нужно со своего сервера отправлять *E-Mail*, но если использовать `smtp`, то банят быстро; типа спам. Хотя по сути отчеты для меня любимого. В *PHP* все из коробки было, а как тут с такой реализацией? Со своего сервера можно сделать? Или мне нужно на *VSP* сервак под почту поднять на Убунту, а потом в го доработать или можно сразу как то в го или есть готовое решение?

Comment: На вопрос вряд ли будет хороший ответ.  Все, кого я знаю, используют *SMTP,*  и у них всё хорошо.  Разбирайтесь, почему вас банят.

Comment: @Ainar-G как бы там квоты

Comment: @Ainar-G я как понял нужно понять сервер черех postfix  а дальше приделать это добро к го , а там хоть через cmd или smtp сервер то свой